# How to set text for each horizontal bar chart in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android

[image]

I want to set text for each horizontal bar chart  in MPAndroidChart.

Please, help me. Thanks so much

Comment: I also not get any solution for MPAndroidChart if any one get then it helpful.

Comment: I have a idea, hope it helpful for u chart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM_INSIDE);
chart.getXAxis().setXOffset(-100);

Answer (score 1):

I have a idea, hope it helpful for u

```
chart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM_INSIDE);
chart.getXAxis().setXOffset(-100);
```

Answer (score 0):

hope it helpful for u

```
    mBarChart = findViewById(R.id.id_horizontal_barchart);
    ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries = new ArrayList<>();
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(0f, 3f));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(1f, 2f));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(2f, 1f));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(3f, 1f));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(4f, 1f));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(5f, 1f));
    ArrayList<String> xAxisName = new ArrayList<>();
    xAxisName.add("Name 1");
    xAxisName.add("Name 2");
    xAxisName.add("Name 3");
    xAxisName.add("Name 4");
    xAxisName.add("Name 5");
    xAxisName.add("Name 6");

    barchart(mBarChart,barEntries,xAxisName);

public static void barchart(BarChart barChart, ArrayList<BarEntry> arrayList, final ArrayList<String> xAxisValues) {
    barChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
    barChart.setFitBars(true);
    barChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
    barChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(25);
    barChart.setPinchZoom(true);

    barChart.setDrawGridBackground(true);
    BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(arrayList, "Values");
    barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
    BarData barData = new BarData(barDataSet);
    barData.setBarWidth(0.9f);
    barData.setValueTextSize(0f);

    barChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    barChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    Legend l = barChart.getLegend();
    l.setTextSize(10f);
    l.setFormSize(10f);
    XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setTextSize(13f);
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM_INSIDE);
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(xAxisValues));
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
    xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(false);
    xAxis.setXOffset(50);
    xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);

    barChart.setData(barData);

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).